# Sequence points in gcc vs turbo compiler different behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

When attempting a competitive programming question small issue was there for me.
code:

```
#include<iostream>


int main(){
    int x = 5;

    x = x++;

    std::cout << x;

    return 0;
}
```

When i tried on gcc 6.3 in cmd in my system the output was:

```
5
```

When my mate tries to run on turbo c on his system output was:

```
6
```

What is this unexpected behavior and why turbo c on his system runs that code.

Is it a gcc version difference?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/251311 ?

Comment: `x = x++;` is **undefined behavior** (prior to C++17, IIRC)

Comment: @RemyLebeau this should be the actual answer?

Comment: "`x = x++;`" - what do you expect to happen here ?  Why would you want to write something like that ?

Comment: @SidS While this does not make sense in the real world, it is a valid expression nevertheless. So it is a good question *why* there are differences in compilers. This might be extended as a pointer example as well. So it could be interesting to predict what happened if 2 pointers point to the same address.

Comment: @SoumyaKanti It should. However, I'ld like to see a more verbose answer with a link to spec. It is not naturally clear, whether the expression `x++` should be evaluated, then post increment is done, after all evaluations the result is assigned *or*  the entire expression is evaluated, then assigned and finally post increments are done. `y = x++ + x++` could be another test case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Could you write a complete answer referencing the specs or point out where this special case is treated in the given duplicate link above?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone it's not a valid expression in C++14 (which OP has specified via tags)